# MSMQ - Create and Send Message

Tags: msmq, message-queue

I have a public queue created in a remote machine. I am able to access the queue, create a message and send it from my workstation. However, when I access the remote machine that hosts the message queue, I do not see any messages. Any ideas on what I am missing? Is there anything that need to be configured to receive messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the security settings on the remote queue - the default setting for any account is "allow sending only".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it to work by removing MessageQueueTransactionType.Single from MessageQueue.Send(message,MessageQueueTransactionType.Single) method.

Seems like there was a mismatch between the Transaction types. I am not what how this works.  

Do you know if private queues can be accessed by a remote computer with your suggestion?

Comment: I can be done, but i had some trouble with this recently and worked around by moving the service accessing the queue to the local machine. If you have a mismatch in the transaction type you'd have to re-create the queue because the transactional type cannot be modified on an existing queue.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by removing MessageQueueTransactionType.Single from MessageQueue.Send(message,MessageQueueTransactionType.Single) method.

It Seems like there was a mismatch between the Transaction types. I am still not familiar how the transaction types work.